# DatePicker without DatePickerDialog with Compose

Tags: android, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog

I'm trying to embed a DatePicker into any composable without using a DatePickerDialog, but I don't know if there is any way to do this.

I've seen that the typical approach is using this dialog, where content is a *DatePicker*:

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun DatePickerDialog(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    confirmButton: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dismissButton: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    shape: Shape = DatePickerDefaults.shape,
    tonalElevation: Dp = DatePickerDefaults.TonalElevation,
    colors: DatePickerColors = DatePickerDefaults.colors(),
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
)
```

But if I use directly a DatePicker without the dialog, I lose some important points:

- I haven't the backgrond surface of the dialog with M3 colors.
- I haven't the lambdas for confirm or cancel (I would like to hide the DatePicker when any action is done for example).
- Seems that the size of DatePicker should be adjusted and not fits well automatically as occurs with the DatePickerDialog

I've read in the M3 specificatios that there is a DockedDateDialog, but seems that is not ready yet: https://m3.material.io/components/date-pickers/overview

I haven't found any answer related to this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy the relevant bits of code out of `DatePickerDialog()` into your own composable. Or, use a third-party date picker composable -- my newsletter archives [have a few](https://jetc.dev/search?q=%22date%22).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but if it's possible, I prefer to avoid that because in the module where I should implement this composable, is not depending on any class or value of M3. I'm using wrappers. The M3 dependencies are in other module.